# angularjs - Inject Angular Wizard into controller fails

Tags: angularjs, wizard

I am using a Angular Wizard and i add 'mgo-angular-wizard' dependency in index.html

This is my controller header:

```
angular.module('angularApp').controller('WorkDialogController',
          ['$scope','$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$modalInstance', 'entity', 'Work',
           '$translate','WizardHandler',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $modalInstance, entity, Work, $translate, WizardHandler) {....
```

I am injecting WizardHandler but when i try to access it, i get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: WizardHandler is not defined`

What i am missing in my configuration?

Comment: Have you included it with `angular.module('angularApp', ['mgo-angular-wizard']);`?

Comment: yes i have. angular.module('angularApp', ['LocalStorageModule', 'tmh.dynamicLocale', 'pascalprecht.translate', 
               'ui.bootstrap', // for modal dialogs
    'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngCacheBuster', 'infinite-scroll','monospaced.qrcode','mgo-angular-wizard'])